# How to host image that can be accessed by PIXI.js without running into CORS issue?

Tags: javascript, graphics, pixi.js

I have been using PIXI.js to create a basic game. When I attempt to play the game at a remote location, I run into a CORS-based issue:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the
remote resource at http://example.com/myimage.png.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

I have attempted this by hosting images externally and on my local machine.

As a workaround, I have been attempting to create my images with javascript using the PIXI library, but I have not found a method to create a sprite from a drawn graphic.
**What is the best way to host images for use on PIXI.js that will not run into CORS related issues?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use the .generateTexture method from the renderer:
http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Renderer.html#generateTexture

If you created your app like this: `var app = new PIXI.Application()` your renderer will be in `app.renderer`

So something like:

```
var redSquare = new PIXI.Graphics();
redSquare.beginFill(0xffffff);
redSquare.drawRect(50,50,100,100);
redSquare.endFill();
var red = new PIXI.Sprite(app.renderer.generateTexture(redSquare));
```